# Illustrator variables / data-driven documents: how to batch-export one file for each data set?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, information-graphics, batch-processing, automation, data-merge

With the *Variables* window in Illustrator you can make something a bit like a data-merge document with lots of variants for different records (InDesign’s data merge is usually better, but I have to use Illustrator for this, for other features that are in Illustrator and not in InDesign).

After setting these up, you get an Illustrator document with a drop-down menu in the *Variable*s window that lets you switch between different many variants on a template.

How do I turn this into lots of static files (or a static file with lots of artboards), similar to the *Create merged document* option in InDesign?

---

Some handy links on Illustrator variables / dynamic documents:

- [Adobe help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-62a2a.html)
- [Video tutorial](http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/quick-tip-data-driven-graphics-using-illustrators-variables-panel/) (someone asks my question in the comments, but there's no answer)
- [Tutorial by Creative Mac](http://www.creativemac.com/2002/03_mar/tutorials/illustrator10datadriven.htm)

---

**Example.** Say, you’ve done the following steps in Illustrator, creating a dynamic document with variants:

1. Create a chart with the graph tool, put some data in it.
2. Open *Variables* window, select the chart, click *Make Graph Dynamic* and create a new graph variable.
3. *Capture data set* from the *variables flyout* menu.
4. Save variable library as XML.
5. Put data in the XML – e.g. for testing you could just open the XML in a plain text editor, find the chunk from `<v:sampleDataSet` to `</v:sampleDataSet>`, and copy and paste it a few times, varying the data values and `dataSetName`.
6. Reload the new XML variable library from the *variables flyout* menu.

You now have a drop-down menu that lets you switch the chart between each data set you created.

Let’s say there were 1,000 variants. How would you turn this into a directory of 1,000 separate files (any format: PDF or AI are both fine) with filenames based on the data set name, without manually switching and doing *Save as* each time?

---

I'd have thought there would be an option, like InDesign Data-Merge’s *Create merged document,* but I can’t find one anywhere. Failing that, I'm sure that *Actions* should be able to do this, but I can't figure out how. If not *Actions,* maybe a script can do it.

Or if that’s not possible directly, is there a way to make one mega-file with an artboard for each data set (which can then be split into separate files)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the data set exporting is very well tucked away.

---

To export the data sets into pdf's you need to do this:

- Make a new action where you simply save a pdf document.
- Then from the corner menu in `Actions` window, select `Batch..`. [image]

You should:

- Select the action you just made
- Select source: Data sets
- and Override action "save" commands.

[image]

Then press ok.

---

I have never used this for thousands of pdf's, so I'm not sure how long it'll take, but that should do the job.

Comment: Awesome! Perfect! p.s. I have to ask - what does your `HULK SMASH!!` action do? :-D

Comment: ...and one tip for anyone following this method: if you're creating lots of PDFs, don't forget to make sure that `View PDF after saving` is ***not*** ticked when recording the save PDF action!! D'oh...

Comment: @user568458 :P HULK SMASH!! does this: **1.** Select all `cmd+a` **2.** Create outlines `cmd+shift+O` **3.** Outline stroke **4.** Save (.ai) **5.** Save as (.pdf) -- It's for logos and such.